# How do I make this code more readable?

Tags: c#, coding-style, readability

I wrote this today and I'm ashamed. What do I need to do to make this chaotic stuff more accurate and readable amongst others?

```
switch ((RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType)Enum.Parse(typeof(RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType), ihdType.Value))
    {
            //REF:This can (but should it?) be refactored through strategy pattern
        case RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType.ReportPlanWithEffects:
            grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportsDataParser(
                            RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportPlanWithEffects(requestNo, RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo(requestNo)));
            break;
        case RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts:
            DateTime factDate;
            try
            {
                factDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ihdDate.Value);
            }
            catch(FormatException)
            {
                grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportsDataParser(
                            RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts(requestNo, RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo(requestNo), DateTime.MinValue));
                break;
            }
            grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportsDataParser(
                            RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts(requestNo, RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo(requestNo), factDate));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always use [an alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) for the very long type `RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures`:

```
using RRCSP = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures;
```

Note: You will need to use the fully qualified name (including namespace) in the `using` directive.

Comment: Or you can put the using directive into the needed namespace.

Comment: @Grozz - I am assuming this is a _type_, not a namespace.

Comment: namespace CurrentNS { using IntKVP = KeyValuePair<int, int>; ... }

Comment: That does shorten things a bit, but you're left with the 'RRCSP' alias in the code, which isn't particularly readable.  It's a handy trick to know, but surely you're better off coming up with a better name for RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures (and associated types) and using that instead?

Comment: @Grant Crofton - Granted, this is just a start. When it comes to refactoring the code as given, this one is a quick win.

Answer (score 11):

On top of what the others have said about shortening the names etc, you should think about extracting the code from the case statement into function calls, so you end up with something like

```
switch (myMassiveVariable)
{
    case RequestReportStoredProcedureType.ReportPlanWithEffects:
        RunReportWithEffects(requestNo);
        break;
    case RequestReportStoredProcedureType.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts:
        RunReportWithFacts(requestNo);
        break;
}
```

That helps to tidy things up a bit.

Answer (score 5):

I am a strong believer in descriptive variable, class and method names. I would always opt for clarity over brevity, however one easy to implement rule is that if you have a part of your names that always repeats, you can pare that out. For example, you have:

RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures

That's good. It explains what it is clearly. However you've got members of that class or object that also start with that name plus differentiating names at the end. For example:

RequestReportStoredProcedureType

This could be shortened to StoredProcedureType, or even arguably ProcedureType.

I know many programmers would argue for something like RRCalcSP or some other completely unclear naming conventions, but I would never sacrifice naming clarity for avoiding line wrap, etc.

Honestly what you have in your original example is not chaotic or shameful. It's just so long that you have to deal with line wrap.

Also, generous use of comments make things much clearer.

Comment: I agree with everything here, apart from the generous use of comments - unnecessary comments can make things even less clear, and generally aren't needed if the code is clear.  I think once the OP's tidied up the names a bit it will be clear enough.

Comment: I think descriptive names are good, but it's also possible to leak implementation details in a name.  A good name describes how the client of a class will use it, not how the class accomplishes its work.  For instance, the BCL contains a Dictionary class (the analogy of looking up entries in a dictionary is readily accessible) and not, for one possible implementation, a LookupMapUsingBalancedBinaryTree.

Comment: You're right about too many comments. In many cases you don't need comments (getThing() // This method gets the thing) but I would make  one further assertion: it's better to have SLIGHTLY too much commenting than too little. It's a hard line to find and walk but it's more important than a lot of people believe.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, one of the biggest issues here is just the length of your variable names.

Obviously, you should give variables/types/etc. descriptive names. But there's a point at which it gets a bit extreme. One guy at my work is notorious for giving methods names like:

`DoSomethingVerySpecificHereIsOneOfItsSideEffectsAndHereIsAnother`

In your case, I notice a great deal of redundancy. For example, you have a class called `RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures`, and then within that class you seem to have an enum called `RequestReportStoredProcedureType`. Since the enum is already a nested type within `RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures`, maybe you could just call it `Type`?

Alternatively, a *very* effective way to shorten these names (at least in this file) would be to use a simple `using` declaration:

```
using E = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType;
```

Then look what happens to your code:

```
using RRCSP = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures;
using E = RRCSP.RequestReportStoredProcedureType;

// ...

// Note: RRCSP = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures, and
//       E = RRCSP.RequestReportStoredProcedureType

switch ((E)Enum.Parse(typeof(E), ihdType.Value))
    {
        //REF:This can (but should it?) be refactored through strategy pattern
        case E.ReportPlanWithEffects:
            grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RRCSP.ReportsDataParser(
                RRCSP.ReportPlanWithEffects(
                    requestNo,
                    RRCSP.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo(requestNo)
                )
            );
            break;
        case E.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts:
            DateTime factDate;
            try
            {
                factDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ihdDate.Value);
            }
            catch(FormatException)
            {
                grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RRCSP.ReportsDataParser(
                    RRCSP.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts(
                        requestNo,
                        RRCSP.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo(requestNo),
                        DateTime.MinValue
                    )
                );
                break;
            }
            grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RRCSP.ReportsDataParser(
                RRCSP.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts(
                    requestNo,
                    RRCSP.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo(requestNo),
                    factDate
                )
            );
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Is this more readable? In my opinion, yes, primarily because it's simply less daunting to look at. Obviously you're making a trade-off, though, as the aliased names you're using are less *immediately* obvious than the original names. Like just about everything else, it ultimately comes down to personal judgment.

Comment: Certainly shorter, but I don't like the 'E' alias.  I know you have a comment, but a good name trumps a comment every time.  (I'm not too keen on RRCSP either, come to mention it).  I'd be more inclined to un-nest that enums, as @Dan Bryant suggested - without doing that, surely you get an LOD violation anyway?

Comment: @Grant: You're right, it's really not great this way either; but as I said, it's less daunting to read, which typically (for me, at least) does make it easier to absorb. As for un-nesting the enum: you could do that, but then it wouldn't make sense to also shorten its name, as others have suggested; so it seems to me it wouldn't buy you much.

Comment: How do you like the name of generic function CopyFirstParameterToSecondAndReturnFalse?  I created such a function for a very specific purpose (grabbing an Exception object in a 'When' clause in vb.net 'Catch' statement, without actually catching the exception), and was debating whether it was better to have the function's naming fit the purpose, or whether it was better to name the function as above, give it the obvious implementation, and then document at the call site why I was calling such a function.  What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

If you have some control over the code that you're using, I'd recommend:

1. Bring the enum RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType to outer scope.  The inner name is already verbose enough that you don't need the outer name to clarify.
2. Try to replace the long class names with names that clarify their intent, without describing the details of how they accomplish their job.
3. Provide an overload of RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts that doesn't require the algorithm parameter, since you can apparently look it up by the requestNo anyway.  That eliminates the verbose call to RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo when you don't need to provide a non-standard algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly this answer is leveraging on other answers to this question, but I thought it would be helpful to make some of the suggestions more explicit.

The class RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedure I would rename to RequestReports.  The StoredProcedure portion to me seems to be an implementation detail that is nobody else's business.  I am not sure what the word Calculating brings to the table so I removed that also.

The enumeration RequestReportStoredProcedureType I would rename to ReportPlan as that seemed to fit the context best (ReportType is also a possibility).  The additional wordiness was removed similar to the reasons the class that encompasses it was renamed.  I left it inside the class as it seems to provide some context, and with the names shortened this seemed like a good idea.

The suggestions to remove the algorithm parameter from the method calls since it can be derived from an already passed parameter seemed like a good one.

Given these changes the code would then look like the following:

```
switch((RequestReports.ReportPlan)Enum.Parse(typeof(RequestReports.ReportPlan), ihdType.Value)) {
            //REF:This can (but should it?) be refactored through strategy pattern
            case RequestReports.ReportPlan.WithEffects:
                Object reportPlan = RequestReports.ReportPlanWithEffects(requestNo);
                grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RequestReports.ReportsDataParser(reportPlan);
                break;
            case RequestReports.ReportPlan.WithEffectsForFacts:
                DateTime factDate;
                try {
                    factDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ihdDate.Value);
                }
                catch(FormatException) {
                    Object reportPlan2 = RequestReports.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts(requestNo, DateTime.MinValue);
                    grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RequestReports.ReportsDataParser(reportPlan2);
                    break;
                }
                Object reportPlan3 = RequestReports.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts(requestNo, factDate);
                grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RequestReports.ReportsDataParser(reportPlan3);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [using command](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/01/13/773.aspx).

Also I beleive (haven't checked) but you can do something similar to:

```
RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedure myShortCut = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType;
```

Then instead of referencing the large lines you can reference `myShortCut`.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the strategy pattern as you commented, or use a Dictionary with delegates(Func<> or Action<>) that based on a type does something. You can shorten the DateTime try/catch by using DateTime.TryParse() method. Other than that, what is most unredeable from your code is the long names, so you may want to put some of those in variable before starting your code

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

i'd advocate extracting the common parts out of the case statement

```
RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType dependingOnType =(RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType)Enum.Parse(typeof(RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType), ihdType.Value);

var EssentialData = null;
var AlgorithmChosen = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo(requestNo);

switch (dependingOnType)
    {
            //REF:This can (but should it?) be refactored through strategy pattern
        case RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType.ReportPlanWithEffects:
           EssentialData  = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportPlanWithEffects(requestNo, AlgorithmChosen);
            break;
        case RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.RequestReportStoredProcedureType.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts:
            DateTime factDate = Datetime.MinValue;

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(ihdDate.Value, factDate)) {
                factDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            }

               EssentialData  = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportPlanWithEffectsForFacts(requestNo, AlgorithmChosen, factDate);

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

grvEconomicCriteria.DataSource = RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.ReportsDataParser(essentialData);
```

You could refine it event more by calculating the

```
RequestReportsCalculatingStoredProcedures.GetAlgorithmNoByRequestNo(requestNo)
```

only once

edit: like this :)